# How to Move up an LandXML Node in VB .NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Given an XML structure like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd">
        <Units>
                    <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
        </Units>
        <Surfaces>
            <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
              <Definition surfType="TIN">
                <Pnts />
                <Faces />
              </Definition>
              <SourceData>
                <Boundaries>
                  <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
                    <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
                  </Boundary>
                </Boundaries>
              </SourceData>
              <Definition surfType="GND">
                  <Pnts />
                  <Faces />
              </Definition>
    <SourceData>
                <Boundaries>
                  <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
                    <PntList3D></PntList3D>
                  </Boundary>
                </Boundaries>
              </SourceData> 


              <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy" />
              <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
                <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
              </Application>
            </Surface>
          </Surfaces>
        </LandXML>
```

I want to move the first SourceData node under Surface sub category but ,above Definition in the Surface subcategory.

Here's the final structure I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <LandXML xmlns="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" date="2014-12-18-06:00" language="English" readOnly="false" time="12:12:16.338-06:00" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0 http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0/LandXML-1.0.xsd">
      <Units>
        <Imperial angularUnit="decimal degrees" areaUnit="squareFoot" diameterUnit="USSurveyFoot" directionUnit="decimal degrees" flowUnit="cubicFeetSecond" heightUnit="USSurveyFoot" linearUnit="USSurveyFoot" pressureUnit="inHG" temperatureUnit="fahrenheit" velocityUnit="feetPerSecond" volumeUnit="cubicFeet" widthUnit="USSurveyFoot" />
      </Units>
      <Surfaces>
        <Surface OID="SIE" desc="Ground Surface" name="Ground">
          <SourceData>
            <Boundaries>
              <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
                <PntList3D>1.5181307542E7 2125297.27 1713.976 1.5181309121E7 2125348.661 1713.65 1.518131357E7 2125401.188 1713.624 1.5181355394E7 2125953.634 1712.622 1.5181471897E7 2127035.359 1711.076 1.5181474238E7 2127060.368 1711.571 1.5181479644E7 2127074.35 1711.4 1.5181484532E7 2127081.58 1711.23 1.5181486144E7 2127083.79 1711.24 1.5181526576E7 2127114.416 1710.763 1.5181604217E7 2127162.511 1710.742 1.518173257E7 2127220.112 1712.713 1.5182046629E7 2127316.035 1716.328 1.5182350908E7 2127362.323 1709.085 1.518238492E7 2126720.863 1678.373 1.5182383044E7 2126559.786 1663.524 1.518236883E7 2126031.128 1708.884 1.5182353785E7 2125775.21 1680.648 1.5182361822E7 2125348.267 1648.468 1.518235892E7 2125223.263 1646.325 1.518233926E7 2124751.224 1640.587 1.5181441405E7 2125081.466 1700.044 1.518132618E7 2125144.398 1708.546 1.5181317827E7 2125194.92 1712.947 1.5181309366E7 2125246.027 1714.161</PntList3D>
              </Boundary>
            </Boundaries>
          </SourceData>
          <Definition surfType="TIN">
            <Pnts />
            <Faces />
          </Definition>
<Definition surfType="GND">
            <Pnts />
            <Faces />
          </Definition>
<SourceData>
            <Boundaries>
              <Boundary bndType="outer" edgeTrim="true" name="Outermost bounding edge">
                <PntList3D></PntList3D>
              </Boundary>
            </Boundaries>
          </SourceData>
          <Project desc="GPS Survey, UTM14 North, Autonomous Base, Geoid 2009, Reedy" />
          <Application manufacturer="USDA NRCS" name="Engineering Field Tools" version="3.4.1.2">
            <Author createdBy="james.reedy" />
          </Application>
        </Surface>
      </Surfaces>
    </LandXML>
```

So far I have come up with this code:

```
Sub MoveUnits(fileName As String)
    Dim file As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    Dim SourceData As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}SourceData")
    Dim tempElement = file.Root.Elements(SourceData)(0)
    tempElement.Remove()
    'Dont know how to add it in the right spot
    file.Save(fileName)
End Sub
```

However it will only output an error at `tempElement.Remove()` saying that it cant remove an object equil to none. So I think in:

```
Dim SourceData As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}SourceData")
Dim tempElement = file.Root.Elements(SourceData)(0)
```

Because It will find any category under LandXML But not any Subcategorys.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to drill down to the appropriate element:

```
Sub MoveSourceData(fileName As String)
    Dim file As XDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    Dim surfaces As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}Surfaces")
    Dim surface As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}Surface")
    Dim sourcedata As XName = XName.Get("{http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.0}SourceData")
    Dim rootElement = file.Root.Elements(surfaces)(0).Elements(surface)(0)
    Dim tempElement = rootElement.Elements(sourcedata)(0)
    tempElement.Remove()
    rootElement.AddFirst(tempElement)
    file.Save(fileName)
End Sub
```

If you need changes to other than the first element, simply change the index.  For instance the first SourceData in the second Surface would be:

```
Dim rootElement = file.Root.Elements(surfaces)(0).Elements(surface)(1)
Dim tempElement = rootElement.Elements(sourcedata)(0)
```

If you will only ever need just the first elements, you can use the `Element` property instead, which can improve performance on large files by only finding the first element instead of all the elements of that name:

```
Dim rootElement = file.Root.Element(surfaces).Element(surface)
Dim tempElement = rootElement.Element(sourcedata)
```

Comment: I have put the code in and I'm not getting any error, but it isn't moving SourceData, SourceData is remaining below Definition. Any Ideas

Comment: Never mind Figured it out thank you very much @tinstaafl